# Powershell script to stitch excel sheets to form a workbook(.xslx format)

Tags: powershell

I have multiple excel sheets with me (.xlsx format).I would like to put them all together to form a workbook with each sheet as a sheet in the workbook itself.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/) powershell module. This can be as easy as `Install-Module ImportExcel`

The basic usage you'll want is to import the excel files you have, then export to a single workbook:

```
Foreach ($file in (Get-Item 'C:\path\to\*.xlsx')) {
  Import-Excel $file.fullname -WorksheetName MyWorksheet | 
    Export-Excel -Path 'C:\path\to\combined.xlsx' -WorksheetName "From $($file.name)"
}
```